# Center of Mass in 2 triangle

Tags: geometry

*I've got a question.*
As you know if we connect the dots on the medians , it makes another triangle inside the main triangle, so here's my questions :

- **1**. Are the line flashes drew rightly? *[As the image]*
- **2**. If we make the second triangle (Red one) bigger , does it have similarity with bigger one? *[As the image]*
- **3**. Are these lines that similar by it's flashes parallel? *[As the image]*
- **4**. Are those triangle's center of mass is at a same place or not?

[image: Click here for the image]

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint for your 4th question is that  all the triangles converge to a common point and that is the point of intersection of medians ie centroid. For 3 rd question Note M and N are midpoints so by mid- point theorem the lines of two triangles are parallel. So if lines are parallel then i hope you know how to make them similar and they are drawn fine.Hope you have got the questions to all of your answers.